# CakePHP: Using Bootstrap Glyphicons as image-links

Tags: image, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, glyphicons

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap Glyphicon as an image-link. This is the current syntax I am using:

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link('<i class="icon-align-left"></i>', array('controller' => 'links', 'action' => 'edit', $link['id'],$contract['Contract']['id'])); ?>
```

The output from this returns a working link, but simply as

```
<i class="icon-align-left"></i>
```

rather than the image.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Side note: Look into [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) - same concept but BETTER.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use escape=>false as documented:

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link('<i class="icon-align-left"></i>', 
    array('controller' => 'links', 'action' => 'edit', $link['id'], $contract['Contract']['id']), 
    array('escape' => false); ?>
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link

Comment: please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557568/display-image-from-database