# display image from database

Tags: php, image, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Table User

```
image(blob type)  
------------------------------
0xFFD8FFE0
```

myController

```
function displayImage($id)
{

        $this->autoRender = false;


        $peoples=TableRegistry::get('peoples');      
        $peoples=$peoples->getRecord([ 'image'])->first();   

        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

         echo $peoples['image']; 
}
```

Model

```
function getRecord($fields)
{
    return $this->find('all')->select($fields);
}
```

But when I set this:

```
<img id="imgPreview" src="displayImage/30">
```

the image does not show anything. When I use `myController/displayImage/30` this shows `Resource id #170` to me!

Why is this? How can I display the image?

Comment: Please share code for the getRecord() function. The Resource id #170 is the mysql resource you need to extract the data from the resource by looping the rows.

Answer (score 4):

You need to read from that returned **resource** to get the actual content (image data)

```
public function displayImage($id)
{ 
    // ... 
    echo stream_get_contents($peoples['image']);
}
```

Here is modified working example of your method. I've assumed, that you have model named `Peoples` with property `image`(BLOB) and `$id` refers to some row in an underlying table

```
public function displayImage($id) {
    $table = TableRegistry::get('Peoples');
    $entity = $table->get($id);

    $this->response->type('jpg');
    $this->response->body(stream_get_contents($entity->image));

    return $this->response;
}
```

Comment: say error stream_get_contents  `Cannot use object of type Cake\\ORM\\Query as array`

Comment: @mhkyazd Seems you are passing `Query` object without executing it. Are you sure you are not calling only `$peoples->getRecord([ 'image'])` without that `first()`? Also you can use object notation to access properties: `$peoples->image`

Comment: @mhkyazd Any progress on this? See edit to my answer, I tried it and it's working, so you should be able to make it work. Only adjust it (associations, etc.) to you specific conditions. Let me know, if you need further help with it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch an image from a user ID?

If that is the case

```
$peoples = TableRegistry::get('Peoples');
$peoples->find('all');
$peoples->matching('Users', function($q) use($id) {
   return $q->where(['Users.id' => $id]);
});

$result = $peoples->first();
$result->users[0]->image;
```

Comment: Are you using Cakephp 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about struggling with the right HTML code to upload images. For that you just have to give to that uploading field in database table column varchar type and then in the view where to upload the image from give it a file type. Something like:

```
   <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('your_column_name', [ 'type' => 'file']); 
    ?>
```

But if your question is about not being able to retrieve or send to index.ctp or to a frontend view the uploaded image, then your solution is here:
[How to retrieve in cakephp3.7 the name as string of an image uploaded trough a form with blob column into a mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333785/how-to-retrieve-in-cakephp3-7-the-name-as-string-of-an-image-uploaded-trough-a-f/57478584#57478584)